# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')

Tags: reactjs, input, buscador

Estoy haciendo un buscador dentro de un modal, cuando este modal abre puede aparacer una lista de elementos tipo number o tipo string.
El caso es que cuando intento usarlo para buscar por numero, me arroja el siguiente error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')
No se como podria hacer para que este buscador me permita filtrar tanto numeros como string, ayuda por favor...

Este es mi codigo :

```
export const filterData = (state, data, setState) => {
  if (data === '') {
    setState(state); // Establece el estado con la lista original de elementos
  } else {
    // Convierte el valor del campo de entrada y el contenido de cada elemento a minúsculas
    const lowerCaseData = data.toLowerCase();
    const lowerCaseState = state.map((el) => el.toLowerCase());
    const resSearch = lowerCaseState.filter((el) => {
      if (el.includes(lowerCaseData)) {
        return el;
      }
    });
    setState(resSearch);
  }
};
```

y aqui es donde llamo a la funcion  y le paso los parametros. El hecho es que me funciona solo cuando los datos a buscar son de tipo string ... Y en algunos casos la lista de elementos puede ser de tipo numero.

```
const handleChangeSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    filterData(dataRow, e.target.value, setDataRow);
    filterData(dataColumn, e.target.value, setDataColumn);
  };
```

Comment: Prueba con `const lowerCaseState = state.map((el) => el.toString().toLowerCase());
`

Comment: Es porque el dato al hacer el render es null la primera vez, prueba intentando usando el operador `?` cuánto es null, quedando de está manera `data?.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Entonces ese `el`en `state.map((el) => el.toLowerCase())` puede ser tipo `string` o tipo `number`? , puede que una condición para evaluar el tipo de dato sea de ayuda.